# How to hide the overflow menu leaving it active by clicking hardware menu button

Tags: android, menuitem

I want to hide the overflow menu (the three dots indicator in the toolbar) but I still need it active If the user click hardware menu button.
I tried this

```
mToolbar.hideOverflowMenu();
```

but not working..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try  toolbar.getChildAt(i).setVisibile(GONE)

Comment: How can I know the (i) for the menu.. thanks!

Comment: I tried this
        for(int i= 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++){
            View v = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
            if(v != null && v instanceof MenuItem){
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

but not working

Answer (score 0):

You should get it after `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

[image]

[image]

[image]